# Need help identifying components! Hardware

Tags: power, connector, pins, hardware, step-down

So recently I have come across a schematic diagram with pictures, but some of the parts in the build (A quadruped robot, more information in the hackaday link below) are not in the schematic, and I can't tell what are these components called, any ideas? Picture is quite vague but its the only thing I can work with. **Schematic diagram** is here https://cdn.hackaday.io/images/9979261594143410055.png

**Link to where I got the pictures**: https://hackaday.io/project/171456-diy-hobby-servos-quadruped-robot

[image: First component]

[image: Second component]

[image: Not really a component, I just don't know what is this connector called]

Comment: Is it the XFMRS 5mm x 5mm inductor? http://xfmrs.com/products/xf5020-2r2m/

Comment: I don't really know, there was not much information regarding it, all i know is that it is used to connect the battery to the servo motors, I thought it was a stepdown module but I'm not quite sure. Do you know what connector that is in the third image?

Comment: I quickly read your link. It says there is a bulk converter 5V 3A for Rpi. I guess the square thing you are asking is an inductor used the switching power supply (I did once use that kind of inductor to DIY a LM2596 switch power supply.) The green connector with thick pins are power pins. Perhaps for the Lipo x 2 = 7.5V input, and 5V USB output to power the Rpi. Just wild guess. I am only a friendly hobbyist. No guarantee no nothing won't melt down or blow up. Have a great locking down weekend.Good luck and cheers.

Comment: The schematic looks wrong.  It has the inputs and outputs of the regulators transposed.

Answer (score 0):

Third one looks like a "Phoenix" style 3.81mm pitch connector (it's been slightly mangled by something). There are several manufacturers for these parts, you don't need to go with the ones from "Phoenix contact" To fit this connector the matrix board would have needed extra holes drilled or the pins would need to be bent, (pins 1 and 3 line up with holes, but pins 2 and 4 will be half-way between holes) or install it rotated 45 degrees.

Second one looks like a "USB charger power module": presumably it makes 5V to run the Adiuino and the Raspberry pi. presumable of of those XL801

The top one is also some sort of DC-DC converter  "HENGE UBEC 8A/12A peak"
REG1,REG2,REG3,REG4 in the diagram